# CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION error in c program

Tags: c, libcurl

This code outputs 60 which corresponds to `CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION`  in the error code in the libcurl [docs](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

> The remote server's SSL certificate or SSH md5 fingerprint was deemed not OK.

I am assuming that my program can't find the public key of the website that it reaches (google.com in this case) or it does not know where it's own public key is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl.h>



int main()
{

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
      CURLcode res;
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com");
      res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      printf("%d", res);
      curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    else
        printf("Done");
    return 0; 
}
```

The program compiled using `msys2 MINGW64` 
The only output I got is `60`

Comment: You need an up-to-date CA bundle to verify the server cert against. Try this: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/12639332)  provides a workaround for this issue but this still does not fix the issue since it does not check the certificate

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

the workaround simply turns off SSL verification for peer and host